# How to generate a gpg for InRelease

Tags: apache2, repository, gnupg

i have created a repository using apache and a folder, know i dont want to use deb [trusted=yes] for my repost and try to generate the key with gpg, 4096bit and the next config

```
personal-digest-preferences SHA512
cert-digest-algo SHA512
digest-algo SHA512
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```

the Error i am getting is this

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.astian.org/debian ./ InRelease' provides only weak security information.

you can visit the website to navigate and have a look on the Release, Release.gpg and InRelease, and the key to be imported is on https://packages.astian.org/
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: for creating the repos, no